# <ul> is not collapsed even though <li> are floated?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

What I know so far is that a parent with nothing but floated children has no height.

In the header for example, I have the left logo floated and the text has an absolute position. The only thing keeping the header from collapsing is the right logo.

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Felix Titling Regular", Times, serif;
  border-bottom: 2px double white;
  font-size: 0;
}

header a {
  display: inline-block;
}

header>a:first-child {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 3%;
}

header>a:last-child {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 3%;
}

#center-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 25%;
  font-size: 16px;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 300%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="index.html"><img src="media/logo-small.png" alt="Godfather Logo" title="Godfather Small Logo" /></a>
  <div id="center-wrapper">
    <h1> loyal capos to the don </h1>
  </div>
  <a href="index.html"><img src="media/logo-small.png" alt="Godfather Logo" title="Godfather Small Logo" /></a>
</header>
```

However, I don't understand why my first parent 'ul' in the 'nav' still has height even though all the li elements are floated.

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 2px double #660000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  background-color: #660000;
}

nav>ul {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav>ul>li {
  min-width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

nav ul ul,
nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

nav>ul>li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

nav>ul>li>ul>li:hover>ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  display: block;
}

ul>li {
  position: relative;
  padding: .4em 0;
  background-color: white;
}

li>a {
  color: #660000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: "Felix Titling Regular", Times, serif;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">wiki</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">media</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">images</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">videos</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="pages/videos/scenes.html">best scenes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">bloopers</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">facts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="pages/about/feedback.html">feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Here's my code on fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/vwb6g740/1/)

Comment: When using floats in your grid layout, the common practice is to clear the float, so the parent element will get the height of its' child elements `.parent-element::after { clear: both; display: block; content: ""; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true for block elements and inline elements, but not for inline-block elements.

> What I know so far is that a parent with nothing but floated children has no height.

You have display:inline-block; set on that parent element.

I can't explain why, but I can reproduce that behavior.

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
}

div {
  background: red;
}

span {
  background: green;
}

i {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div><i>test</i></div>
<span><i>test</i></span>
<p><i>test</i></p>
```

Comment: Which element are you referring to?

Comment: nav>ul is the parent with the floated children yet it has height.